# I cant find out how to do subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, magento, dns, subdomain, digital-ocean

How do I tell whats making my sub-domains? I swear I went through every .htaccess file in my server.

I just inherited the server from the previous IT guy and its a mess. As far as I know it could be straight DNS that makes the sub-domains.

I have:

```
www.theprinterdepo.com
```

and

```
preprod.theprinterdepo.com
demo1.theprinterdepo.com
demo2.theprinterdepo.com
```

but I cant figure out how to make this work. I've tried going through all the htaccess files but couldn't find anything that mentioned what and what redirects were there.

It seems there is a 301 permanent redirect to

```
dev.theprinterdepot.net
```

to

```
www.theprinterdepo.com
```

Comment: I found in cpanel where redirects are. But none are active. Yet when i go to: www.theprinterdepot.net or preprod.theprinterdepot.net it auto redirects to the printer depo.com

Comment: found out its a magento deal. You cant just duplicate an instance of magento to another folder and call it live server. you have to edit the settings and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two components to domain/subdomain.

One is the DNS entry that creates the domain/subdomain (what IP address resolves) and the other is the web server virtual host configs that allow the server to respond.

So depending on how this is hosted, either WHM/Cpanel for all the above, or your registrar's DNS and actual digging in the server configuration for the virtual host entries.

.htaccess is way after the fact on this one as DNS must resolve the server name and then point to a vhost that understands the request.